# File Tree from remote server

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-5

I'm using laravel's SSH module to connect to remote servers: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/ssh

I need to create a file tree on my site from the file structure on this server.

For example I run `ls` and covert the result into a file tree.

I need pointed in the right direction on how do go about this?

Something so note is I need to follow directories to get the content of them also for the file tree.

If you need any further info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use command "ls -l" instead. This tells you which item is the directory and which is regular file.

Otherwise it is standard recursive task.

1. List all files in root dir
2. Keep in memory all directories found
3. Create all files in this dir that are in remote system
4. Go into each of the directories and repeat the process

Comment: This gives me all the out in 1 line though, which is very difficult to work with.